# how to implement "back to" functionality using JavaScript for all browser

Tags: javascript, browser

**widndow.history.back()** is not working in firefox as in chrome.
In firefox it goes to the previous page and comes back to the current page like back and forth.
 But in chrome it is going to the previous page and then that's previous page and so on..
so how can I implement this **functionality(as in chrome)** in firefox browser..

```
    <div class="link2Back"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="history.back()" class="col-xs-12">Back to ... </a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="index.jsp" id="backButton">GO BACK</a>


var backbutton = document.getElementById("backButton");
backbutton.onclick = function(e){
  e = e || window.event; 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  window.history.back();
}
```